# Starting out with RTE and Javascript

Tags: javascript, rte

I'm somewhat new to Javascript, not HTML/CSS or PHP/MySQL, just JS. I have a quick question. If I were to try to make my own RTE Text editor for a system that I'm building, does anyone know where I would start out? Books, tutorials, whatever is fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't re-invent the wheel.

Building a rich-text editor is a lot of work, and making it work in most browsers is even more work.

Instead, you should go with an existing option, such as [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com) or [TinyMCE](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/).

If you want a learning exercise, I recommend starting with something simpler.

Comment: I checked out CKEditor, I like it. I've been using TInyMCE, but there's some things I want to do with my system but cant. I'll take a looksy at CKEditor. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

how about [Tiny MCE](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/). You can use it as is or read the code - it is open source

Answer (score 0):

The Google Closure library has a [great rich text editor](http://closure-library.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/closure/goog/docs/class_goog_editor_Field.html). [Here is a demo](http://closure-library.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/closure/goog/demos/editor/editor.html).